Is ACU the Standard way of calculating compute in azure app service plan?
I am trying to understand ACUs to standarize the compute unit across app service plan. , just correct if I'm wrong here:
I understood ACU as just as compute power , so let us consider my ASP S1 is 100 ACU 1 core ... And if it hits 50% cpu percentage in a 5 min time period, does it mean that the asp consumes 50 ACUs out of 100
So similarly if I have an S2 plan which comes with 100 ACU two cores , so that means I have 200 ACUs
So the same 50% in S1 will it be now 25% in S2 because now i know that it consumes 50 ACUs.. thus for a machine with 200 ACUs it's gonna come to 25%
My question are basically:
 - can we multiply core and ACU to get the total     ACU (compute power)

 -and me converting the cpu percentage to ACUs will it help me choosing the right ASP ? 


Your understanding isn't far off. However, an ACU is a relative measurement and incorporates memory as well as CPU. The memory is proportional to the CPU cores

So similarly if I have an S2 plan which comes with 100 ACU two cores , so that means I have 200 ACUs.

The S2 plan has 200 ACUs. This doesn't translate directly from the number of cores in all cases. There are dedicated plans where the underlying CPU clock rate will be higher, or lower, for example. And plans which have a higher memory to CPU ratio. These affects ACUs.

Can we multiply core and ACU to get the total ACU (compute power)

No. Although ACUs and CPU cores and memory are proportional in your S1 and S2 example, they are not across all plans, as per above.

and me converting the cpu percentage to ACUs will it help me choosing the right ASP?

It's quite reasonable to use this as a guide when sizing your plans, yes. But don't forget, you need to consider memory and storage requirements of your apps.
